# Stop activity restart on font change

Tags: android, fonts

Whenever I change font activity starts from onCreate(). How can I stop this?

Comment: activity restart on font change? wow...

Comment: write any activity and test it on a device code has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 7):

The reason for this is that changing the font scale fires a configuration change. You can see a list of that things that fire these configuration changes [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

To avoid it, you could add the attribute `android:configChanges="fontScale"` - but you would then need to handle that configuration change yourself by overriding [`onConfigurationChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29).

I advise that you read about [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) before you proceed.