# Android Widget Breaks on System Font Change

Tags: android, widget

When I change the system's font size on an android device, my widget breaks. The fields switch back to the defaults, they won't update, and touching the widget doesn't open the app anymore. It works fine when I do a full system restart. Is there something that happens on a system font change that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8254938/2591920]) answer considers adding the `android:configChanges="fontScale"` attribute to the manifest. However, it is considered [bad practice](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) since you have to manually handle the config change.

It is expected behavior for Activities to restart when such an event happens. Have you considered storing your state during `onStop()` and restoring it `onRestart()`?

Comment: I appreciate your response. There is no onStop() or onRestart() in an AppWidgetProvider. There is, however an onEnabled()/onDisabled(). I tried to restore the Intents in onEnabled(), but to no avail.